# Android Listview - Load each row on thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview

Is it possible in java to multi-thread each row in listview?
My listitems is a description from files and when there are hundreds of files, the loading takes too long. I want it to be multi-threaded so I can see the items loaded one-by-one.

Here is my code.

```
    Controller_Listrecord adapter;
    ListView lstposts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstviewrecordlist);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> details = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    File f2 = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()); // The location where you want your WAV file

    File[] files = f2.listFiles();
    String text="";
    HashMap<String,String> map=null;
    for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++){

        byte[] data = Base64.decode(files[i].getName(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        try {
            text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
            //text = files[i].getName();
            map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            File file = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+files[i].getName());
            mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+files[i].getName()));


            Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());


            map.put("recordingtitle",text);
            map.put("recordingduration", mplayer.getDuration()+"");

            String thedate ;//= DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(lastModDate);

            thedate = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm a", lastModDate)+"";

            map.put("recordingdate",thedate);

            details.add(map);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    adapter = new Controller_Listrecord(this,details);
    lstposts.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: you may set empty adapter to your ListVIew, and then add them to the adapter dynamically

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add new items on my adapter? Because I use custom adapter, and there is no adapter.add() function.

Comment: depending on how exactly you implemented your custm adapter, you may need to add that method manually

Comment: Thanks, I implemented the add function. But I have difficulty in implementing the thread. I gets an error sometimes.     [CODE]for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++){

                    addItemToList(thethis,i,files);

        }

Comment: which error it gives?

Comment: Here.  android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. I also sometimes get this error.  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10

Comment: this means you have implemented something incorrectly. But nobody knows what before you add your code

Comment: Thanks Vladyslav Matviienko, I fixed it, I put the adapter.add() function on runOnUiThread() and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

Than you can add a synchronized function (to avoid collisions) that adds an item to that adapter:

```
public synchronized void addItemToList(String item){
    adapter.add(item);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

And then in your thread call that function each time that an item is received:

```
public void runOnBackground(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                String item = getItemFromSomwhere();
                addItemToList(item);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add new items on my adapter? Because I use custom adapter, and there is no adapter.add() function.